# AR Core - Depth API to distance

Tags: android, augmented-reality, distance, arcore

I am using [ArCore](https://developers.google.com/ar) to get a [depth map](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/overview).
I want to know how to transform the [DEPTH16](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#DEPTH16) map to distance in meters

Answer (score 1):

The Developer site has some detail on this:

- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/overview

From there you can see that:

> Each pixel in the depth map is represented by an unsigned 16-bit integer. The least significant 13 bits contain the distance in millimeters to the estimated surface from the camera's image plane, along the camera's optical axis.

Its worth remembering that each pixel's DEPTH16 value also has a confidence value, so you may want to check that and blend it into your calculations to avoid any misleading values also - the confidence value is in the first 3 bits:

> The confidence value is an estimate of correctness for this sample. It is encoded in the 3 most significant bits of the sample, with a value of 0 representing 100% confidence, a value of 1